# EF6 how to automatic set AutoDetectChangesEnabled to true when Excute linq SingleOrDefault

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, inspector

Due to the performance of the reasons , My DbContext default setting:

```
      Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

But i want to tracking entity change state if using Single() or SingleOrDefault() query , and SaveChanges to db , follow is manual set code:

```
        try
        {
            context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
            var user = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => Id == 1);

            user.LoginCount += 1;
            context.SaveChanges();

        }
        finally
        {
            context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        }
```

How to to achieve this automatic inspect the SingleOrDefault query EXCUTE?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve entities by no tracking when using list queries and track them when using single retrieval?

Comment: @TaherRahgooy ,Yeah, that's what I mean.